# navigate.push is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, navigateurl

I got the error in react reuter dom version related to navigate.push is not a function.
this following error disturbing my whole clean code, It'll be great if somebody helps me to resolve this.

`This is my code`

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        navigate.push("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };

  const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        //it successfully created a new user with email and password

        if (auth) {
          navigate.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using React Router v6:
use `navigate("/")` instead of `navigate.push("/")`

Comment: @VishalMishra Please, mark as right answer

Comment: How do I make it work if I use: BrowserRouter as useNavigate because when I try that it says Navigate is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and ran into a sweet nugget to fix the issue, code example below...

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/routers';

onPress={() => {
  const pushAction = 
  StackActions.push('ProfileAnimal', { animal_id: item.id });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileAnimal', {animal_id: item.id});
  };
```